# nginx location block configuration

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

i'm trying to serve files of specific urls from a subfolder of my webserver, matching the url with the location config of nginx, it works for the first level "/newsletter" but not for the deep one like "/newsletter/ID456/"

this is my nginx configuration (partial):

```
root /home/myuser/www;
server_name www.mysite.it;

      location / {
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
      }
  
#    location ~^/newsletter/(.*)$ {
      location /newsletter {
                root /home/myuser/www/newsletter;
#             try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
#             try_files $uri $uri/ /newsletter/index.html;
}
```

As you can see i've done many tests, but no one works.
My goal is to serve this type of url: "https://www.mysite.it/newsletter/myid" and serve files from this directory "/home/myuser/www/newsletter".

if i digit "https://www.mysite.it/newsletter" it works, but if i digit "https://www.mysite.it/newsletter/A5143" it doesn't.

I can figure out how to solve it.

thanks.

Comment: What is the full pathname for the file you expect to be returned using the URLs `/newsletter/ID456/` and `/newsletter/A5143`?

Comment: The "/IDXXX" is variable, it's an angular application and i take the id from the url and make something. My goal is to serve all /newsletter/xxxx urls with /newsletter/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You have files in the directory `/home/myuser/www/newsletter`, which are accessed using URLs that begin with `/newsletter/`. But ultimately, you want to route requests that begin with `/newsletter/` to `/home/myuser/www/newsletter/index.html`.

The correct value for `root` is `/home/myuser/www` as `newsletter` is already part of the URL. See [the `root` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details.

But as this value is already defined in the `server` context, you do not need to repeat it in the `location` context.

For example:

```
root /home/myuser/www;
...
location /newsletter {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /newsletter/index.html;
}
```